# Call a Java Applet from Flex

Tags: apache-flex, applet

I'm working on Flex application and I need to open a Java Applet from Flex (e.g. clicking a button). In particular I'd like to open imageJ, a particular imaging program that could work as application, applet or be integrated in a web page. Is there a way to call it from Flex? I've seen a couple of tutorials that explain how to call a single function in another Java file from Flex, but I'm not so sure that it is what I'm looking for.
Thanks for your answers,
cheers,

David

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a better way, but if I was doing it, I'd write a JavaScript function that would load the Java applet (could be as simple as `document.write("<object …>")`), then use Flex's [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call that JavaScript.

Comment: Yep - you are really going to want to work this with the ExternalInterface

Answer (score 0):

Expose a public method in your applet, which the flex would call. You could load the applet the following way. It is a sample program, to call java methods and get a value from java, you can do changes as per your need

```
    <object
    id = "MyApplet"
    name = "Some name"
    classid = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" width="0" height="0">
    <PARAM NAME = "CODE" VALUE = "com.my.applet.MyApplet.class" >
    <PARAM NAME = "CODEBASE" VALUE = "." >
    <PARAM NAME = "ARCHIVE" VALUE = "applet-client.jar" >
    <PARAM NAME = "cache_option" VALUE="No">

    <PARAM NAME = "java_version" VALUE="1.6+">
    <param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
    <comment>
        <embed
            name = "MyApplet"
            type = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" \
            CODE = "com.my.applet.MyApplet.class" \
            JAVA_CODEBASE = "." \
            ARCHIVE = "applet-client.jar"
            cache_option = "No"
            scriptable = false
            pluginspage = "http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download"
            width="0" height="0"
        >
            <noembed>
            </noembed>
        </embed>
    </comment>

</object>
```

With the above in your html file( I am not explaining everything) , the applet will be downloaded and ready to use. Now on click of a button on your flex app, you should have something like below.

```
var returnedStringFrom java:String=ExternalInterface.call("document.MyApplet.functionInJava",stringParam);
```

Note : MyApplet is the name in the object declaration above, the functionInJava is a public function in the the java class com.my.applet.MyApplet. It takes a parameter and returns a string parameter. The Java program will look like below.

```
package com.my.applet;

public class MyApplet{
//other methods..

public String functionInJava(String stringpm){

// your implementation 
return "SomeString";
}
}
```

Happy coding.