# How to check %USERNAME% using actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, shell, actionscript

My project I'm working on is a FLEX internal website that also can be logged into when trying to access from a remote location. I'm trying to have it display the username of the current logged in windows user when they access the site locally. I have tried using NativeProcess to access the command line but that is unavailable when working with a web application. Any ideas on how I would be able to do this?

Comment: You won't able to do this in a browser based application.  It may be possible to create an ActiveX control that gets this information; but I'm not sure how compatible that will be in multiple browsers.

Comment: Hmm ... I was looking at signed java applets. Would I possible be able to do it using one?

Comment: I have no idea; beyond my realm of experience.

Comment: Something here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944812/call-a-java-applet-from-flex

Comment: Maybe this will help? has a couple answers, one for IE, one for FF:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do something like that where I work.  Unfortunately, it doesn't use the frontend but makes a request to a backend process.  The suggestion I have only works through a vpn also if I recall correctly.  Basically, on my PHP backend, I allow Windows authentication, and then use the result of that COM object call to get data about the current user.  I then send that data back to my Flex frontend, web or AIR and display that to the user as well as restrict access to various parts of the app.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing something like that with java, but without vpn, wouldn't it just display the windows info of the back-end server?

Comment: @user2192652 Yes, it would display the windows Active Directory stuff which contains the user name.